# Naming convention for REST endpoint for dashboard

Tags: rest

I have a REST api that looks similar to the /annotations/[id]/events[id]/flights/[id] and I want to create a dashboard to create an annotation with some number of events and flights.  What is the naming convention for something of this nature ?  /annotations/dashboard ?

Comment: REST doesn't care how you name things or how you structure the URIs, what IS important though is that you return links clients can use to progress on. These links should have meaningful link relation names so a client can determine the purpose of the link. By following this principle you help to decouple clients from your API and make the clients more robust to changes in your API.

Answer (score 0):

`/annotations/dashboard`works fine, assuming the dashboard is only for annotation-related things.

If the dashboard functions more like a general homepage, it'd be best to just use `/dashboard`, and use `/annotations/...` for annotation-related endpoints only.

In most cases, things like this are merely aesthetic. However, it does help to have API endpoint URIs that make sense based on what they're for/related to.